# R summarize unique values across columns based on values from one column

Tags: r, unique, aggregate

I want to know the total number of unique values for each column based on the values of var_1.

For example:

```
Test <- data.frame(var_1 = c("a","a","a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), var_2 = c("bl","bf","bl", "bl","bf","bl","bl","bf","bc", "bg" ), var_3 = c("cf","cf","eg", "cf","cf","eg","cf","dr","eg","fg"))
```

The results I am looking for would be based on the values in var_1 and should be:

```
var_1 var_2 var_3
a     2     2
b     2     1
c     3     4
```

However, after trying various methods (including apply and table) -  aggregate has been the closest thing to what I am looking for, but this script results in a summary of the total number of entries for each value of var_1, but the total is not unique

```
agbyv1= aggregate(. ~ var_1, Test, length) 

var_1 var_2 var_3
a     3     3
b     2     2
c     5     5
```

I tried

```
unqbyv1= aggregate(. ~ var_1, Test, length(unique(x)))
```

but that didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second `aggregate` approach was almost right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
Test %>%
      group_by(var_1) %>% 
      summarise_each(funs(n_distinct(.)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(Test)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), var_1]
```

If there are NAs

```
setDT(Test)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(na.omit(x))), var_1]
```

Or you can use `aggregate`.  By default, the `na.action=na.omit`.  So, we don't need any modifications.

```
aggregate(.~ var_1, Test, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)) )
```

Comment: Awesome, that works great. I'll have to play around more with dplyr as it seems to do the trick. Have a great day.

Comment: Just noticed that NA values are not omitted, how do I add that bit of script to this? I tried adding na.omit() %>% at the beginning but that doesn't work right.

Comment: In my large dataset I just noticed that NA values are not omitted using this script. I tried adding na.omit() %>% at the beginning but that doesn't work right because it is removing all rows with na values, rather than just ignoring them when counting down each column.

Comment: thanks for the extra help, but it's still not right for a larger dataset with NA values. The aggregate line above removes all NA rows, so I get a much abbreviated unique count for each column. I just want it to not count the NAs but count the rest of the unique entries in each column.

Comment: Short term consideration: `uniqueN` is not in the data.table package on CRAN, but `function(x)length(unique(x))` works in its place

Comment: @Ina.Quest `na.omit` should probably go near the `each`-column operation, like `n_distinct(na.omit(.))`, I'd guess

Comment: @Frank, adding the na.omit with the n.distinct as above worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank I was trying the suggestion, but it gives me error.  `Test %>%group_by(var_1) %>%   summarise_each(funs(n_distinct(na.omit(.))))#
Error: Input to n_distinct() must be a single variable name from the data set`
I used `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`

Comment: @akrun I didn't try it myself before, and now see the same error as you. Beats me how that solved the OP's problem :) Oh, I just made up this command (having never read about `dplyr`) and it seems to work: `Test %>%group_by(var_1) %>% mutate_each(funs(na.omit)) %>% summarise_each(funs(n_distinct(.)))` Piping isn't so bad :)

Comment: @Frank  I think there are some problems in different versions.  This one also ends up in error after I change some values to `NA`.  ie. `Test %>%group_by(var_1) %>% mutate_each(funs(na.omit)) 
Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
apply(Test[-1] , 2 , function(y) tapply(y,Test$var_1,function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for the dummydata above for my larger dataset I am getting an error: Error in tapply(y, oh$RM, function(x) length(unique(x))) : 
  arguments must have same length... any idea what that means?

Comment: @Ina.Quest `oh$RM` will have zero length if you got the column name wrong.

Comment: @Erin - I tried: apply(oh[-1] , 2 , function(y) tapply(y,oh$RM,function(x) length(unique(x)))) - where oh is my dataset and RM is the column I want to sort by. When I run the script I get the error I posted above.

Comment: Without looking at your actual dataset it's hard to say what the problem is.